# Video game "Gish" will only launch from command line

Tags: lubuntu, games

Platform: Lubuntu 11.10 x64

Program: [Gish](http://www.chroniclogic.com/gish.htm)

When I try to launch Gish from the command line (`/opt/gish/gi.sh`), there are no problems. But when I try to launch it from the LXDE menu, it will not start.

Contents of `/usr/share/applications/gish.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Game;ActionGame;AdventureGame;ArcadeGame;
Exec=/opt/gish/gi.sh
Path=/opt/gish
Icon=x-gish
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Gish
```

I tried changing `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true` to debug it, but then I just got a blank terminal, and the game didn't start.

**Edit**:

Here is some additional information, as requested by Eliah Kagan below:

- I tried editing `/usr/share/applications/gish.desktop`, as recommended, but it had no effect
- However, `~/.xsession-errors` contained the following error:

  ```
  [: 8: x86_64: unexpected operator
  ./gish_32: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
  ```

  I think there's a problem with the `/opt/gish/gi.sh` shell script. This is its contents:

  ```
  cd /opt/gish/

  MACHINE_TYPE=`uname -m`
  if [ ${MACHINE_TYPE} == 'x86_64' ]; then
    ./gish_64
  else
    ./gish_32
  fi
  ```

  I'm not too familiar with Bash, so hopefully someone else can point out the error.

  **I have a 64-bit machine. I think that when the script is run from the command line, it's properly launching the 64-bit version (`/opt/gish/gish_64`), but when it's run from the LXDE menu, it's launching the 32-bit version (`/opt/gish/gish_32`), which is causing the `libGL.so.1` error.** However, this may be related to my `libGL.so.1` problems with [2 other games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79359/hib-games-aquaria-penumbra-cannot-find-libgl-so-1-even-though-it-exists/79429#79429).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General advice for this sort of problem

Try changing `Exec=/opt/gish/gi.sh` to `Exec=sh /opt/gish/gi.sh`.

If that doesn't work, try changing the `Path` line so it specifies whatever directory you're in when you run the program in the Terminal. Assuming you're in your home directory, the line would become `Path=/home/aberration` where `aberration` is replaced by your username on your Ubuntu system (if different).

If that doesn't work either, then please open the file called `.xsession-errors` located in your home directory (in PCManFM you'll have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or click `View` > `Show Hidden` to make this and other files that start with `.` appear), select its entire contents, copy it to the clipboard, paste it at the [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and edit your question to include the URL for it. Make sure that you have attempted to run the game from the LXDE menus very shortly before opening `.xsession-errors` so that messages pertaining to the failure are likely to appear near the end of the file.

## Advice specific to the error in .xsession_errors and the script's specific contents

It seems likely that your suspicion is correct; that is, that when the script is run from LXPanel, the test for whether or not your architecture is 64-bit is not working properly. I am not sure exactly what is going wrong. But since the script does not have a leading hashbang line (i.e., a line starting with `#!` followed immediately by the full path to the program that is to act as the script's interpreter), it is probably being run by a different shell when you run it from LXPanel than when you run it from `bash` in LXTerminal. When you run it from LXPanel, it is probably being run by the default shell (`/bin/sh`, which is a symbolic link to the `dash` shell), whereas when you run it from within `bash` in LXTerminal, it is being run by `bash`. The script uses some unusual syntax that I am not familiar with, which might reflect that my scripting knowledge is a bit rusty, but might be because I write scripts for `sh`/`dash` rather than `bash`.

I recommend that you back up the script (`sudo cp /opt/gish/gi.sh /opt/gish/gi.sh.old`) and then try editing it by adding the line `#!/bin/bash` to the very top, to make it run with `bash`. Then see if it runs properly.

If it does, then I recommend submitting a bug report to the creators of `gi.sh`. (I am guessing this is not an Ubuntu package, since it is installed in `/opt`, so you'll have to check if the project has its own bug reporting guidelines first.) While the fix detailed above is appropriate for Ubuntu, a fix likely to work properly on a wider variety of Unix-like systems (Linux-based and otherwise) would be to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` rather than `#!/bin/bash` since `env` is in `/usr/bin` significantly more often than `bash` is in `/bin`. (The authors should also be aware that `bash` is not present on all Unix-like systems, so if Gish is intended to run on systems that are likely not to have `bash` and it doesn't otherwise require `bash`, they might want to edit the script.) And either way, a script that requires `bash` should not be suffixed `.sh`, but should instead be suffixed `.bash` (or not at all).

If that change does not make the script run properly, then it's still worth checking to see if the problem was that the 32-bit version of Gish was running instead of the 64-bit version. So you can make a new `.desktop` file with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Game;ActionGame;AdventureGame;ArcadeGame;
Exec=/opt/gish/gish_64
Path=/opt/gish
Icon=x-gish
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Gish
```

Running from that `.desktop` file--assuming it works--should confirm that the problem is that the wrong executable is being run (and should also work around the problem for you, so you can run Gish from LXPanel).

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made above. I may have made some headway on the source of the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @aberration I've edited my answer to provide advice specific to the information you've just provided.

Comment: That was it, it seems to be working just fine now!

Comment: @aberration If you submit a bug report and it's public (most bug reports are but I don't know what kind of bug tracking system Gish uses), please post a link to it here--then other users with the same problem will find it when they search and find this page.