# Message: SDL_GL_LoadLibrary Error: Failed loading libGL.so.1

Tags: games, libraries, glib

All of my games are giving me this error: 
Message: SDL_GL_LoadLibrary Error: Failed loading libGL.so.1

I have found this [HIB Games (Aquaria & Penumbra) cannot find libGL.so.1 even though it exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79359/hib-games-aquaria-penumbra-cannot-find-libgl-so-1-even-though-it-exists/88115#88115)

but sudo apt-get install libg

l1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 wont work:

```
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

glxgears works fine and i have libGL:

```
visgean@rewitaqia:/opt/Aquaria$ locate libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that entering

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is discussed [at github](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3093).

Essentially it consists of deleting or renaming the following file.

```
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```